# Input tag, how to reset the number to 1 on event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm building an html Snakes And Ladders game. In my settings screen I have an input tag where user needs to choose a board size, and according to his choice, he will get a maximum number of snakes and ladders to choose too.

If he chooses 7x7 board and goes to the input tag (`type=number`) of the snakes and ladders he can select 9, but then if he changes the board size to 5x5 he can choose only up to 5 snakes and ladders. the thing is that the "max" attribute changes to 5 (using ajax) but it's still written 9 in the small box of the input (type="number")..

How do I reset what's written inside the little box? I want the user to see "1" every time he changes the board size...and that only then he could choose his number of snakes and ladders.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you mean without seeing your code.  Please post your HTML etc.

Comment: Set the _value_ property in a line next to where you set the _max_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the input value to one with

```
$("#input_field").val("1");
```

(given that the input field has the css-id "input_field").
http://api.jquery.com/val/

You need to call this when a certain event occurs (like a change in the other form element).

You can do something like (untested)

```
$("#select").change(function() {
    // change max value via ajax if needed
    $("#input_field").val("1");
});
```

(given that the select field has the css-id "select")